# Capture Google Chrome Dev Tools Display Data

Tags: javascript

Google Developer mode. Log Google Chrome display output.

I want to capture the purple display output from Google Developer mode, of my scrolling script.

I can not find anything on the Google Developers site.

Any suggestions?

BTW - How can I add an image? My reputation is not high enough?

Thanks

Robert Seymour

Comment: ![scroll output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8QA9.png)

This worked.

Comment: From your description, it seems that you want to record the changes of #header 's attributes?

Comment: @robert you can post a image url

Comment: That is correct obfish The whole data stream. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks  Madhawa Priyashantha